# Plot not showing up in Jupyter

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure()
```

I should get a pop up empty graph with no value but nothing shows up in jupyter just the output:

```
<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

Why is there no graph showing up?

Comment: Why do you want an empty graph to render?

Comment: I am following it from a book where apparently it pops up and while i enter ax1, ax2 and so forth the graph updates automatically.

Comment: This wouldn't work in a Jupyter notebook - only if you run this in the Python REPL.  Try doing this in the Python REPL instead and you'll see that a blank figure pops up.

Comment: in the book they say: `If you are in pylab mode in IPython, a new empty window should pop up.` Is there a way to change this mode?

Comment: To what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `%matplotlib inline`, use `%matplotlib notebook` to have the output display within the notebook.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

fig = plt.figure()
```